# Check if the particular string is present in a output of shell script using shell command

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk, grep

I have a shell script (test1.sh) which returns the following output

```
 Employee ID          emp Type  return type  Admin User
   us321000034006755    ITdept      access    Itadminuser
```

I wanted to check if the output contains string ITdept for that I have used the following:

```
if ./test1.sh | grep -q 'ITdept'; 
then
    echo "found"
else
    echo "Not found"
fi
```

Along with this I wanted to check the the strings Employee ID us321000034006755 too since it doesn't return any fruitful results with the command I am using not sure how to put this through. Am I missing something? any advice would be great

Comment: You need to check output from another script or inside test1.sh?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the output will contain the string `us321000034006755(separator)ITdept`:

```
if cmd | grep -q '[[:<:]]us321000034006755[[:>:]][[:space:]]*[[:<:]]ITdept[[:>:]]'; then
   ...
fi
```

If you have the two substrings in variables:

```
if cmd | grep -q "[[:<:]]$user_id[[:>:]][[:space:]]*[[:<:]]$user_dept[[:>:]]"; then
   ...
fi
```

The `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` will match on word boundaries.

---

It would be a lot easier to do this using `awk`, [as RomanPerekhrest suggests](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/391951/116858), or

```
cmd | awk '$1 == "us321000034006755" && $2 == "ITdept" { print "found"; exit } END { print "not found" }'
```

Answer (score 1):

If the output will always contain only 2 lines - ***awk*** solution to check by multiple fields:

```
awk 'NR==2 { 
         printf "%s%s\n",($1=="us321000034006755" && $2=="ITdept")? "":"not ","found" 
     }' <(sh ./test1.sh)
```

Comment: This gives an error 
:-./test2.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./test2.sh: line 7: `     }' <(sh ./test1.sh)'

Comment: @Rebbeca, it's your script error: it indicates `line 7`. My script doesn't have 7 lines. Make sure you have specified the path to that shell script properly and there are no other errors in your shell script

Comment: this in the content of file in test2.sh:-  
./test1.sh
awk 'NR==2 { 
         printf "%s%s\n",($1=="us321000034006755" && $2=="ITdept")? "":"not ","found" 
     }' <(sh ./test1.sh)

Comment: @Rebbeca, I've posted my approach as independent script. You should not have been put it into your script to call itself, that's pointless. Run the above awk script as is

Comment: Ah thanks a lot for pointing out the error :-)
just one question if I need to check whether 'ITdept' or 'Emp ID' or one more lets say ('access') field is present what do I need to do should I increase the NR==3 and then add in awk as : printf "%s%s\n",($1=="us321000034006755" && $2=="ITdept" && $3 "access")? "":"not ","found"

Comment: just wanted to know that any "string" I want to check will this check in all of the following and do the job

Comment: @Rebbeca, you can check field value by specifying its number, for ex. check if "access" is in 3rd field: `awk 'NR==2 { 
         printf "%s%s\n",($1=="us321000034006755" && $2=="ITdept" && $3=="access")? "":"not ","found" 
     }' <(sh ./test1.sh)`

Comment: Thanks the script above checks the lines but there is no way to implement anything after the results, if the output contains not found I need to do exit 1 where can I place the following in above script ? This help would really solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

If you need to execute this check inside another script you can do that with   something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

var=$(./test1.sh | grep -c ITdept)

if [ $var > 0 ];
then
    echo "found"
else
    echo "Not found"
fi
```

Script counts the number of strings which contain one or more 'ITdept' words.

Or in single line (with awk):

```
./test1.sh | grep -c ITdept | awk '{if ($0==0) print "not found"; else if ($0>0) print "found"}'
```

correct me if I misunderstood your task.

Comment: you can shorten `grep | wc -l` using `grep -c`

Comment: Thanks for the help
If I need another field in as acceptable in 'emp Type' ->ITdept or ITdomain then what to execute?

Comment: You need only replace `ITdept` word after `grep -c`. If 'emp Type' contain spaces you need to place it in quotes